# Angular 2 Динамическая смена шаблона

Tags: angular2

Добрый день! Изучаю Angular 2 и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Если пользователь не авторизирован то у него должна отображаться лэндинг страница, а когда авторизирован должны отображаться другие страницы.
В AppComponent я сделал шаблон лэндинг страниц, и не могу понять как поменять шаблон AppComponent после авторизации пользователя.
Возможно думаю не в том направлении и это делается другими способами?

Comment: это должны быть два разных компонента - один для лендинга, второй для основного приложения

Comment: Хорошо, если пользователь уже авторизирован как менять компонент?

Comment: можно с помощью роутера, можно с помощь `ngIf`

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Нужно делать 2 компонента, то подмена должна быть на уровне provide в root компоненте